Seeking journal for theoretical papers publishing
I want to publish a short review article on some aspects of mathematics education. Can you please introduce some Scopus indexed journals which consider such these paper for publishing? I do not look for leading journals.
Thanks a lot for your time.

Relevant: What are the leading journals in mathematics education?

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematics_education_journals

Does this answer your question? What are the leading journals in mathematics education?

@JRN Actually I am not looking for leading journals. I just look for a scopus index journal  to publish a short review article in mathematics education.

Permit me to give a listing of the journals in which I have seen articles of a high quality. In order to meet this criterion, journals must: [1]. Have at least 3 years of continuous existence and/or be SCOPUS referenced; [2]. Possess an editorial board with sufficient qualifications to adequately address articles in the field; [3]. Not appear on any list (known to me) of predatory publishers.
These are very low standards, and I would expect top journals to reject a substantial proportion of (even excellent) work submitted to them.
The best mathematics education journals in the field, based on historical significance, impact, and citation metrics, include:

Journal for Research in Mathematics Education (JRME): First published in 1970, it is a leading journal in the field and has been instrumental in developing and discussing research within mathematics education.
Educational Studies in Mathematics (ESM): Another prominent journal, it has been a key platform for reporting and discussing research in mathematics education and undergraduate math teaching.
Zentralblatt für Didaktik der Mathematik (ZDM), now known as The International Journal on Mathematics Education: First published in 1969.

These have high impact factors, but they may or may not be what you are looking for. Teaching and pedagogy conferences are often excellent venues to disseminate mathematical instruction strategies.
I'm giving a rather broad description because I am unsure of the sort of resources you are looking for.
Respectfully,
Jonathan Kenigson
